# SQL update table using result of another query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to update the table(orders)after calculate the total amount of that order, I successfully calculate the total amount, but I cannot find way to update the table using the result.

code I successfully calculate the total amount:

```
SELECT orders.orderid, 
       SUM(ordersdish.quantity*dish.price) AS total
FROM   dish 
JOIN   ordersdish 
       ON ordersdish.dishid = dish.dishid 
JOIN   orders 
       ON orders.orderid = ordersdish.orderid 
GROUP BY orders.orderid;
```

Result:
[total amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6zT0.png)

Code I tried to update table(orders):

```
UPDATE orders
SET    total = t1.total
FROM   (
        SELECT orders.orderid, 
               SUM(ordersdish.quantity*dish.price) AS total
        FROM   dish 
        JOIN   ordersdish 
               ON ordersdish.dishid = dish.dishid 
        JOIN   orders 
               ON orders.orderid = ordersdish.orderid 
       GROUP BY orders.orderid  
      )t1
 WHERE  orders.orderid = t1.orderid;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from
(select orders.orderid, SUM(ordersdish.quantity*dish.price)as total
from ' at line 3
```

And here is the table "orders":

[image: table "orders"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax in MySQL use `JOIN`:

```
update orders o join
       (select od.orderid, SUM(od.quantity * d.price)as total
        from dish d join
             ordersdish od
             on od.dishid = d.dishid  
        group by od.orderid
       ) t1
       on o.orderid = t1.orderid
    set o.total = t1.total;
```

Note that `orders` is not needed in the subquery, because the `orderid` is in `orderdish`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this answer.

```
UPDATE o
SET o.total = t1.total
(SELECT o.orderid, SUM(od.quantity * d.price) AS total 
FROM dish AS d 
JOIN ordersdish AS od ON od.dishid = d.dishid 
JOIN orders AS o ON o.orderid = od.orderid 
GROUP BY orders.orderid) t1
WHERE o.orderid = t1.orderid;
```

Comment: This code doesn't work for me, but still thank you for trying to help me.